# I can not scroll in react native Application

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, genymotion

Hello I am new React Native . I created my first application and I noticed there is problem .
I can not scroll in my app . When you create a website, if the height of your elements exceeds the height of the page, you have to scroll , but in react native when my application elements exceeds the height of the page , my application doesn't scroll and I can't see any more of my application .
how can I fix that ?
I still didn't export apk from my application , but it happens in android emulator (genymotion) .

Comment: Please show your code as a [mcve]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please wrap your component in a [ScrollView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview).

Should look something like this:

```
<ScrollView>
 <YourComponent />
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your component with scrollview or you can use flatlist. with flatlist you can do it horizontal too

```
<ScrollView>
</ScrollView>

<Flatlist
/>

<Flatlist 
horizontal
/>
```

the document is in the react native web